# Question about the Flowout Theorem - why is the generating smooth vector field nowhere tangent to $S$ tangent to the flowout from $S$ along $V$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. The last sentence in (c)states that the smooth vector field $V$ is tangent to the submanifold $\Phi(\mathcal{O}_\delta)$. However, the proof of (c) does not contain any proof to this. So I believe this is just a result that follows from the fact that $\Phi(\mathcal{O}_\delta)$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$ containing $S$, but I cannot see why. In the case of (d) this is clear since this would be an open submanifold of $M$, but how do we get that $V$ is tangent to $\Phi(\mathcal{O}_\delta)$, or the flowout from $S$ along $V$ in the general case, i.e. for any $p \in \Phi(\mathcal{O}_\delta)$, $V_p \in T_p \Phi(\mathcal{O}_\delta)$?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is because
$
V(\phi(t,p)) = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\phi(t,p)
$
and by definition, $\phi(t,p) \in \phi(\mathcal{O}_{\delta})$, so that $V$ is the velocity vector of a path in that submanifold! This is what is meant by "$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $V$ are $\phi$ related".

Comment: @Didier Doesn't $\partial/\partial t$ and $V$ are $\phi$  related mean $d\phi_{(t_0,p)}(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{(t_0,p)}) = V_{\phi(t_0,p)}$? This is what is written in the proof of (b).

Comment: Yes, and by definition, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi = d\phi \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$